# Where is admin bar supposed to appear?

Tags: admin-bar

Where in the page's HTML is the admin bar supposed to appear? On my blog it is added to the footer section, with the result being that there is a gap above it when viewing the blog on mobile phones. (The admin bar has `position:absolute;` at small resolutions, and so does the footer it's contained within.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to be in the footer, and it's positioned with CSS. This is partly because at the time that it was introduced there wasn't a standard hook in themes for placing something at the very top of the page. Instead it is added to the `wp_footer` hook.

It's the theme's job to make sure it accounts for the presence of the admin bar, which it can do using the `admin-bar` body class that's added when the bar is present.

Comment: Any tips on getting rid of the gap on small screens?